# images/links in the gridview not shown/working from the production server using mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to MVC2, I have populated a gridview with user details, which have Images and links to another page. On my development machine everything works fine, but on my IIS 7.5 nothing seems to come that easy, images are not displayed, when clicked on links they show 404.0 error page.

1) My published website shows the template and images on the main master page.
2) My Index.aspx has a grid which populates the images, by making calls to the database as follows:  '
                        Width="50px" Height="50px" />
3) It also has a hyperlink which on click should navigate to another page, but instead it shows a 404.0 error page.

My pre-requisites is as follows:

1) I have included all the DLL's needed in the bin folder.
2) My master page has the code of Url.Content to get the css/styles.
3) Have give permissions of IUSR, IIS_IUSR, Network to the folder.

Please help me asap in this regard.

Thanks,
Ravindranath

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("VisitorMaster.ID", "/Visitor/showImage/{0}") %>'
```

with:

```
ImageUrl='<%# Eval("VisitorMaster.ID", "~/Visitor/showImage/{0}") %>'
```

Notice the `~/` which will be replaced by the name of your virtual directory.